# I can't get PHP mysql select with date

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have date database entries like the format 2011/01/08 06:10:11, but I need to SELECT dates with the following select:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE start = '".date("Y-m-d")."'");
```

So PHP doesn't select anything!
When I set the time in the data base to the format 2011/01/08 00:00:00, the PHP selects this day

Please help me selecting the date whatever the time was.
THX

Comment: you are searching using a date format, when your field is a datetime field.

Comment: is it a `DATETIME` field on MySQL ? If not, update the type of your field. Then see one of the proposed solutions

Comment: what if you change the type of field to date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 You can use this.
SELECT * FROM <TABLE>
       WHERE date >= ‘2005-01-07’ AND date < ‘2005-01-07’ +
    INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

dont forget to replace ‘2005-01-07’ with the date you want. Same question has been discussed [here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/181536)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE start LIKE '".date("Y-m-d")."%'");
```

observe i added % after your date and be sure you have something in your table coresponding to that date you are searching for

Answer (score 2):

Try the following query

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `start` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '".date("Y-m-d")."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to extract just the date part and query that (where ? is your date):

```
SELECT id FROM events WHERE DATE(start) = ?
```

The problem is that this doesn't use indexes. It's better to write the query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM events WHERE start BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

The two question marks are your date with `00:00:00` and `23:59:59`.